# wrong answers in comments section

Tags: discussion

I notice sometimes that people add wrong answers in comments section. Is there any way to down vote them or commenting again with their name tagged is the only option.

Comment: "_Is there any way to down vote them_" -- Nope. "_commenting again with their name tagged is the only option_" -- Yes. Correct them. Not all people are experts. All make mistakes. We learn through mistakes. Stack Overflow helps people to learn a lot. And **Don't flag those comments**.

Comment: @CoolGuy: "Don't flag those comments" Why on earth not? Proposed solutions don't belong in comments.

Comment: @JoshCaswell IMO, if there is an answer posted with the contents of the comment, then the comment can be flagged for deletion, giving relevant details. Otherwise, I don't think the comments should be flagged for moderator attention (or any other option).

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I think rene's answer explains "why not" pretty well.

Comment: I am not sure why this discussion got 4 down votes in an hour. Can someone explain the reason behind this? Are people really obsessed by this discussion?

Comment: Yes, we are somewhat obsessed on meta, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). A best guess for the down votes is probably that users don't think there are wrong answers in comments and don't like comment down voting. That last bit is proposed earlier so *lack of research* could also be a reason.

Comment: *"I notice sometimes that people add wrong answers in comments section"* that isn't possible, comments are comments, not answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I constantly add wrong answers as comments. That is by design.

I leave comments if the question is unclear. Due to its unclearness you are more prone to leave a comment that is at best a good guess. Based on assumptions other users leave different best guesses. In the end one comment deemed to be the right one. That comment should be promoted to an answer by inviting the poster of that comment to submit his answer. That comment is also the signpost for future visitors that the other suggestions in the comments are noise.

In an ideal world Stack Overflow wouldn't need comments (if I recall correctly in the early design stages it was considered to not have comments at all). Questions that are asked correctly in the first place don't need comments, they can be answered after reading.

Too many noisy comments are often a sign that the question is of poor quality. Using the existing moderation options like down voting, flagging, close voting on the question is more effective. Visitors see the close notice and/or down votes and wouldn't bother going over the comments while the comments help the OP in improving the post because they understand how much context they need to add to prevent readers go down the wrong route. If the post was improved, invalidating all comments you can use a custom flag and ask the moderator to remove all comments because they are now stale.

Answer (score 6):

Many people leave wild guesses in comments, like "try this, it might just work" and many problems are solved that way. Mostly unless the Answer is immedeatly obvious to me I engage in discussion with the Asker in comments, which also includes suggestions as to potential Answers. If any of these suceed, I make them into an actual Answer, but not before. I think that is not that bad of a practice.